# Can Apache HTTP Server serve dynamic content?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

Can Apache HTTP Server serve only static content? Tomcat is used to serve Servlets/JSP. Can Tomcat serve other dynamic contents like perl, PHP etc?

Comment: "Can Tomcat serve other dynamic contents like perl, PHP etc?" - you ment Tomcat or Apache here?

Answer (score 19):

Apache HTTP Server (http://httpd.apache.org) has:

- CGI support: [mod_cgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cgi.html). 
  This will run almost any dynamic content, you can even write a CGI in Bash.
- WSGI support: [mod_wsgi](http://www.modwsgi.org/)
- FastCGI support: [mod_fcgid](http://fastcgi.coremail.cn/) (CGI, but more efficient)
- Perl support: [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org)
- PHP support: [mod_php](http://www.php.net)
- Python support: [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) (using mod_wsgi is recommended)
- Ruby support: [mod_ruby](http://www.modruby.net) (thanks to [David Holm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216178/can-apache-http-server-serve-dynamic-content#216205))
- Bridge to serve Java content through a servlet container such as Tomcat: [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc), [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html)
- Plus, an API to program your own apache modules that'll enable you to do as you wish, here's a repository of some of the existing modules: http://modules.apache.org

If you meant if Tomcat can, it cannot outside of a Java environment, it is only a servlet container. That said, Java can execute some other scripting languages and thus you could write programs to generate content in all supported [scripting engines](https://scripting.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course Apache is able to serve dynamic content! mod_perl, mod_php, and so are the modules you plug to Apache to give him the ability to serve them.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: Yes :P

[mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) 
[mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [mod_ruby](http://www.modruby.net/en/).